# How i can access method from jframe to jpanel?

Tags: java

In my `btcFrame` class I have the method

```
private void closeButtonMouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
        this.dispose();
}
```

In my `BtcTitleBarPanel` I have in button for that I tend to close the frame. In the constructor I am adding my listener to `closeButton` like below.

```
closeButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
         closeButtonMouseClicked(evt);
     }
});
```

Problem is I cannot reach `closeButtonMouseClicked` method within the panel. How should I be doing to solve this?

Images in case.
[Methods from jframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu72M.jpg)
[Methods in jpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRhmy.jpg)

Comment: The images make this somewhat difficult to follow. Could you paste the actual code? Also, is the jpanel code in the same file/ an inner class of the jframe code?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a getter within the `Panel` for the `closeButton`. After initializing the `Panel` in the `frame` I would add the listener to button within the `Frame.` Like, `btcPanel.getCloseButton().addActionListener(new ...);` and within this action listener you could close the `frame`, like  `btcFrame.this.dispose()`
Though I am not sure if that is a good practise, I almost always create new classes for listening events, but in this case of yours maybe helpful.

> PS(Out of topic): You should see how to name classes and methods, your
>   naming style is wrong.(i.e classes starts with Capital etc.)